# Gif running in loop instead of single iteration

Tags: java, android, android-studio, animated-gif

I want to play [gif](/questions/tagged/gif) only once, i have tried everything available on internet but nothing worked for me. I am getting gif images from drawable folder. When i play this gif file it is playing only one time but when i use this gif in my android studio app it is playing in loop. But I want to use it only once not in loop. I have tried timer to hide the gif but it is not working as i want.

Class: GifImageView

```java
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Movie;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.InputStream;


public class GifImageView extends View {

    private InputStream mInputStream;
    private Movie mMovie;
    private int mWidth, mHeight;
    private long mStart;
    private Context mContext;

    public GifImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    public GifImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public GifImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        this.mContext = context;
        if (attrs.getAttributeName(1).equals("background")) {
            int id = Integer.parseInt(attrs.getAttributeValue(1).substring(1));
            setGifImageResource(id);
        }
    }


    private void init() {
        setFocusable(true);
        mMovie = Movie.decodeStream(mInputStream);
        mWidth = mMovie.width();
        mHeight = mMovie.height();

        requestLayout();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        setMeasuredDimension(mWidth, mHeight);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        long now = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

        if (mStart == 0) {
            mStart = now;
        }

        if (mMovie != null) {

            int duration = mMovie.duration();
            if (duration == 0) {
                duration = 1000;
            }

            int relTime = (int) ((now - mStart) % duration);

            mMovie.setTime(relTime);

            mMovie.draw(canvas, 0, 0);
            invalidate();


        }
    }

    public void setGifImageResource(int id) {
        mInputStream = mContext.getResources().openRawResource(id);
        init();
    }

    public void setGifImageUri(Uri uri) {
        try {
            mInputStream = mContext.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            init();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("GIfImageView", "File not found");
        }
    }
}
```

Main Activity

```java
gifImageView = (GifImageView) findViewById(R.id.GifImageView);
gifImageView.setGifImageResource(R.drawable.hellofinal);
```

Please let me know how can i make this code to run gif only once.

Thank you.